# Relax ng - restricting total string length (maxLength) for mixed content

Tags: xml, xsd, constraints, relaxng

Is there a way to restrict the length of the contents of a mixed content element, or is there another way to do it?

I would like the Relax ng schema to require that the text inside the "attribute" element – in my sample XML below – is limited to a certain number of characters.

Sample XML:

```
<attribute>
    , <tag>ART_QUANTITY</tag> single page etc. 
    Any number of characters is currently accepted here... 
    I would like to restrict this to the same number of characters 
    as in the source of this text, which is a database field.
</attribute>
```

My current Relax ng schema, that doesn't care about the length.

```
<element name="attribute">
    <mixed>
        <!-- The text may contain references to other fields, which we indicate (surrond) with a tag -->
        <zeroOrMore>
            <element name="tag">
                <data type="NMTOKEN"/>
            </element>
        </zeroOrMore>
    </mixed>
</element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that this is possible in RELAX NG. Probably the easiest way would be to serialize the contents of the "attribute" element to a string, and check the length of that, using whatever programming language you're using. (see e.g. the Python [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#serialisation) library)

Comment: It's another company that's requesting a schema for our XML, so I don't have control over the validation tool or language.

Comment: Is it important that the tags are accessible in the main XML document? The only other solution I can come up with is to escape the tags.

Comment: The tags are part of the text (tag markers are not the standard XML ones) in the database, but were made into elements when exported as XML, for another company's application to be able to "lock" them, while the remaining text is shown as editable. I believe that that other application require that the tags are real xml elements. I'll inform my customer about the length requirement, that it can't be set in the schema. It seems that this is not possible with XML Schemas (XSD) either.

Comment: Right. So couldn't you escape the XML here (`&lt;tag&gt;ART_QUANTITY&lt;/tag&gt;`), and have the other application unescape the tags?

Comment: Other application, making use of this XML, are not under our control. I don't know how it would handle escaped strings. I just know that we were once asked to make the "tags" in the text into real XML elements, I guess because that other application was not as easily adapted as our XML. I'm making this schema now, a few years later, and I would rather not change the format of the XML, since it could affect other customers.
I'll set your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

If your RNG processor accepts Schematron rules, specify a Schematron rule saying "string-length(string(.)) < 255" (or whatever).

If your RNG processor doesn't accept Schematron rules, but only pure RNG, I think you're out of luck.